# In CSS, can I style an image only if it actually displays (is not showing alt text)?

Tags: css

I am writing some CSS to style some images on a website. Some of the styles I am applying, though they look good on the images, would be problematic if for whatever reason the image didn't load and the site displayed the alt text. For example, I mirror some of the images with `transform`s.

Is there some way I can target an image in my CSS *only* if the image is actually loaded and displaying, but not if it has fallen back to the alt text?

As an additional note, the reason I am using CSS to style the images, rather than just actually modifying the images themselves, is that I am using the same image multiple times on the page as an icon for a list, and just want to add a little variety to each instance. I'd rather not have 6 different versions of the same image on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```css
.image-not-loaded-yet {
  /* your css for when the image has not yet loaded */
}
```

and then

```html
<img onload="this.classList.remove('image-not-loaded-yet')" class="image-not-loaded-yet" src="path/to/image.jpg" />
```

or the opposite, add the class only when the image has finished loading:

```css
.image-ready {
  /* your css for when the image has fully loaded */
}
```

and then

```html
<img onload="this.classList.add('image-ready')" src="path/to/image.jpg" />
```

If you want to apply this to all images on a page, you can add an event listener to each `img` like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    for (const img of document.querySelectorAll('img')) {
        img.addEventListener('load', () => img.classList.add('image-ready'))
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd hoped for a pure CSS solution, but it appears that may not be possible. I think the first option is probably the better choice; then any alt text will still be legible if for whatever reason the JavaScript doesn't load either. I just have remember to add the 'not-loaded' class to all the images in the HTML...

Comment: I found that it's necessary to set the third `useCapture` parameter of both `addEventListener` calls to `true`. Otherwise there is a pretty noticeable delay before the style takes effect.